# When am I supposed to divide by two in circular permutation problems?

Tags: probability, permutations

In class, the teacher discussed the problem which asked to find the number of arrangements for a necklace with 10 beads of different colours and said we had to divide (10-1)! by 2 to account for symmetry. How come this is not the case for all circular permutation problems? Couldn't all problems with arrangements in a circle be considered symmetrical or am I misunderstanding something? For example, if there were 5 people sitting at a round desk why is the number of arrangements 4! and not 4!/2?

Thanks very much.

Comment: It depends very much on the precise problem statement.  You would divide by $2$ (with some possible adjustments) if two mirror-image arrangements are considered to be the same.  That's reasonable for a physical necklace, although for the sake of clarity that should be stated explicitly.

Comment: The problem just said: Ten beads of different colours are strung on a necklace. How many different arrangements are there?

Comment: You can flip a necklace upside-down and get another workable necklace. You can't really flip a room upside down, so the "humans at a circular table" problem, whether you should divide by 2 depends on the details of the question: do you only care about who's sitting next to whom, or do you also care about which member of each pair of neighbors is on the left and which is on the right? (It is pretty common for textbook problems in combinatorics to be written ambiguously, by the way.)

Comment: I was under the assumption that the symmetry was left-right symmetry not flipping it upside down. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @ConnorHarris But like why would I even want to flip it in the first place?